# Facebook Login Error 400 Bad Request - PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to fix a fb login error. This code was setup before I started working on the site. Apparently it used to work. I have looked at the fb documentation and the code looks correct. Here is the call:

```
$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' . $site->facebook_app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode('http://' . $site->domain . '/facebook.php?oauth_callback') . '&client_secret=' . $site->facebook_app_secret . '&code=' . get('code');

$token =  file_get_contents($token_url);
```

The response is:

`failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
' in .../facebook.php on line 21`

The output of `echo $token_url` is:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=#####&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mypdxhomes.com%2Ffacebook.php%3Foauth_callback&client_secret= ####&code=AQClZMJ1NUYIwwXUABCw3g8hVhRFavrmQfCr5b-dS6PkVqA40WNfBhQTWHe7V7-q7HUDk2OTS50KGUHEa3TMYADWgkYp688rlSnGNyeetkFYWBuFrWOdeo_wBjdErBQ7n1iNHzetqMvlMtW9KK9TEmnIxmwXEdPl-T3CkRNbGp4g2oCSvXI_ozRo6LWDJMqg6nLq54ibag7k8muhjGZ97CYs`

I have looked at a lot of posts about this issue, though none have helped me resolve my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to this here: [Facebook Access Tokens - Server-Side Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833134/facebook-access-tokens-server-side-authentication/10877126#comment20695473_10877126)

Ended up using the FB PHP SDK